# Adding a server to nestjs swagger gives a permission error

Tags: node.js, swagger, nestjs, openapi, nestjs-swagger

When I add new server to a nestjs DocumentBuilder `.addServer('http://localhost:7071')` it thows a permission error when I try to execute routes at generated swagger page.

[image]

At the browser console it thows this error:

```
Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:7071/api/session/signin' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:7071/api/session/signin' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.
```

I already enable cors at the nestjs app with no luck!

```
app.enableCors();
```

Maybe I'm missing some security policy at the DocumentBuilder? Something like `.addSecurity()`? If it is the case How can I add this security policy?

Comment: Does the server running on port 7071 allow for calls from the server running the swagger page?

Comment: Yes, the server is accepting connections from any clients

Answer (score 5):

This error is caused by wrong CORS config. To fix it:

- Update swagger by adding :

```
.addServer('http://localhost:3000')
```

- Add origin in CORS config (the address you're using) :

```
app.enableCors({origin: 'http://localhost:3000'});
```